# Many to many cleanup

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a many to many table that has become a bit of a mess and I'm looking to update the schema to prevent this happening in future. To do that first I need to clean up the existing data to use as the source of a merge script. Not knowing quite how to term this kind of query hitting Google hasn't really helped.

Broken down simply this is what I'm looking at and what I'm aiming to extract.

```
DECLARE @TestTable
TABLE ([IdA] INT, [IdB] INT);

DECLARE @Expected
TABLE ([KeyId] INT, [MemberId] INT);

INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 1),
    (1, 3),
    (4, 1),
    (12, 4),

    (5, 6),
    (6, 7),

    (8, 9),

    (11, 10)

INSERT INTO @Expected
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (1, 12),

    (5, 5),
    (5, 6),
    (5, 7),

    (8, 8),
    (8, 9),

    (10, 10),
    (10, 11)
```

- Lowest Id of a group should be considered the key
- Number of members of a group will always be less than 20
- Ordering isn't important so long as the resultant dataset is correct

Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question; how does the Expected table relate to the test table?  Can yo udemonstrate what you've tried?

Comment: How is the group defined? Why (12, 4) becomes (1, 12)?

Comment: I see, they share the same path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of achieving what you are trying to do:

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2518)

```
--Let's copy the rows in as they are to begin with
INSERT INTO 
  @Expected
SELECT
   [IdA]
  ,[IdB]
FROM 
  @TestTable


--Lets switch the column values where the higher ID's are in column B  
UPDATE @Expected
SET [KeyId] = [MemberId], [MemberId] = [KeyId]  
WHERE [KeyId] > [MemberId]

--Now lets set the KEY IDs
UPDATE
  E
SET
  E.[KeyId] = E1.[KeyId]
FROM
  @Expected E
INNER JOIN
  @Expected E1 
ON
  E1.[MemberId] = E.[KeyId]

--and you wanted mappings for the keys to themselves in your result set, so let's add those
INSERT INTO
  @Expected
SELECT
  [KeyId]
 ,[KeyId]
FROM
  @Expected E 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM @Expected WHERE [KeyId] = E.[KeyId] AND [MemberId] = [KeyID])

SELECT DISTINCT 
  * 
FROM 
  @Expected
```

Note that I'm selecting DISTINCT at the end because I haven't removed duplicates from the result set.

Comment: Well I was hoping there would be a way to do it with a single query and no table variables (I'd been looking towards CTE) but this works perfectly, great solution! Cheers